# How to filter Datagridview That Fill By Webrequest And Dont Have Datasource?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I created a Winforms C# application, and then filled a Datagridview in form load with a web request from website database (database can't control remotely).

In the form load I disable some columns. Now I want to filter datagridview by columns that the client write in textbox.

This is my form load code to fill Datagridview:

```
MyWebRequest Showrequest = new MyWebRequest("https://websitename.com/connector.php", "POST","metod=showform&Table=Propertys");
            string shreqres = Showrequest.GetResponse();

            string[] propertytablerows = shreqres.Split('♣');
            for (int i = 0; i < propertytablerows.Length; i++)
            {
                string propertytablerows1 = propertytablerows[i];
                string[] propertytablerow = propertytablerows1.Split(',');
                propertydatagrid.Rows.Add(propertytablerow);
            }
            int[] hidecolumns = {3,10,11,12,14,16,19,20,21,25,26,27,28,29,31,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,50,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,48,67,68,69,72,73,74,75,76,79,80};
            for (int i=0;i<hidecolumns.Length;i++)
            {
                propertydatagrid.Columns[hidecolumns[i]].Visible = false;
            }
```

And my code in textbox textchange to filter datagridview:

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in propertydatagrid.Columns)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(col.Name);
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in propertydatagrid.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
            }
            propertydatagrid.DataSource = dt;

            DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
            dv.RowFilter = "Owner LIKE '" + owner.Text + "%'";
            propertydatagrid.DataSource = dv;
            propertydatagrid.Refresh();
```

After loading form, there is no problem and datagridview fill and some columns hidden but when I write in textbox program crashed.

Comment: You can put the data into a `DataTable` after you load data from web. Then to show data,  set the `DataSource` of `DataGridView`. To filter data use [`DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Thanks for comment but whats difrent from fill Dtattable from webload or datagridview? I think is not working too.